# ProgressDialog not dismiss in small and large and xlarge screens

Tags: android

now i use

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
```

to use ProgressDialog in my App but when i tested it 
in normal screen in android emulator it dismiss but when i use it in small
and large and xlarge screens it worked and not dismiss 
how i can fixed this problem

source code

```
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
```

in create method

```
loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

i use it like this

```
loadingBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.posts_loadingbar_title));
loadingBar.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.posts_loadingbar_message));
loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
loadingBar.show();
```

to dissmiss

```
loadingBar.dismiss();
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I think it would be good to include more of your code. While it is good that the code is potentially calling dismiss on the dialogue, it is difficult to answer the question without seeing all the code that can trigger the dismiss call. Regards.